# Titanium: How to determine the screen width when using SplitView?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I'm used to using `Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth` all over my app to get the width of the window.

But with SplitView on the iPad `Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth` still returns the total screen size of the iPad (as it probably should).

How can I determine the actual available screen width for the app while using SplitView?

I don't mean SplitWindow BTW.  This is in regards to SplitView where you can line up two different apps next to each other on the iPad

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the width your uiElement using postLayout event

```
var uiWidth;
myElement.addEventListener('postlayout', postlayout);
function postlayout(e){
    uiWidth = e.source.rect.height;
    myElement.removeEventListener('postlayout', postlayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to determine how wide a certain view is, is to use `toImage()` on the UI element, and then get the size.

So... when you do

```
console.log($.myWindow.toImage().rect.width);
```

You should get the width of the window. Which should be the width allocated to your app.

Comment: this is very memory consuming, I wouldn't do a toImage() for a whole window every time there's a resize. The other answer works perfectly.